# Implementing Generic Repository and UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository-pattern

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).

I got to a stage of calling a repository using `_unitOfWork.XYZRepository.Get()`, now to take it further I want to write an interface for my `UnitOfWork` class and inject it to my controller.

I am not sure whether I need write interface for `GenericRepository` or `UnitofWork` class or both.

Can some one guide me in this as to what needs to be done to instantiate a repository with interface instead of `private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();` as shown in the link above.

Comment: [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) is a very popular DI framework.

Comment: I am aware about Ninject but not sure how to proceed with it to inject GenericRepository/UnitofWork into my controller, could you tell me what would be IUnitOfWork???

Comment: DBContext(Repository) ObjectContext(UnitOfWork) in EF

Comment: Yes, you need to create interfaces for both. Are you doing unit testing?

Comment: Thanks Ben, Yes I want to write unit test as well, could you give an idea what IUnitofWork and IGenericRepository will look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [Autofac](http://autofac.org/) for this purpose. In my Global.asax.cs file

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerApiRequest();
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof (LocationTypesRepository).Assembly).Where(
                type => type.Name.EndsWith("Repository")).AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

and then in my controller

```
public class LocationTypesController : ApiController
{
    private readonly ILocationRepository _locationRepository;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private readonly IAuthenticatedUser _user;

    public LocationTypesController(ILocationRepository locationRepository,
                                   IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, 
                                   IAuthenticatedUser user)
    {
        if (locationRepository == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("locationRepository");
        if (unitOfWork == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("unitOfWork");
        if (user == null) 
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");

        _locationRepository = locationRepository;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _user = user;
    }

    public IEnumerable<LocationType> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            IEnumerable<Location> locations = _locationRepository.GetAllAuthorizedLocations(_user.UserName);
            _unitOfWork.Commit();
            return locations.Select(location => location.LocationType).Distinct().OrderBy(location => location.LocationTypeId);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest));
        }
    }
```

Essentially leveraging a DI framework and placing the interfaces as parameters to your repositories (or in my case a WebApi controller)

Answer (score 2):

Modify your repository constructor to accept a unit of work, via its interface:

```
public MyRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
}
```

Then you instantiate your repository, passing the appropriate unit of work in via the constructor. Alternatively, wire-up your IoC container of choice and let it do the heavy lifting.

[Here](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Windsor-tutorial-part-one-getting-Windsor&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)'s a nice tutorial on using Castle Windsor with ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thanks David, Could you have look at the tutorial that I followed and give me an idea as to how to move ahead. I am not looking to make it more complicate by use a package "Windsor Castle".

Comment: I don't see the value in the Unit of Work in this example. It's just an abstraction over the EF Context. To get this working your way, you would have to modify the Repositories to accept a UnitOfWork in their constructor but then provide more abstractions over the context's methods. I'm not sure it's worth it. Just make your repositories dependent on the Context and use the Context as your Unit of Work, which it is anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Based on suggestions I have made following changes...

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    IQueryable<T> Get();
    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Insert(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    void Save();
    T GetByID(Object id);
}

public class GenericRepository<C, T> : IGenericRepository<T>
    where T : class
    where C : EFDbContext, new()
{

    private C _entities = new C();
    public C Context
    {

        get { return _entities; }
        set { _entities = value; }
    }

    public virtual IQueryable<T> Get()
    {

        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
        return query;
    }

    public virtual T GetByID(object id)
    {
        return Context.Set<T>().Find(id);
    }
}

//NinjectControllerFactory
private void AddBindings()
{
_ninjectKernel.Bind<IGenericRepository<Product>>().To<GenericRepository<EFDbContext, Product>>();
}

//Controller
[Inject]
public IGenericRepository<Product> ProductRepo;
public ProductController(IGenericRepository<Product> ProductRepository )
    {
        ProductRepo= ProductRepository ;
    }


//Inside Action
model.Products = ProductRepo.Get();
```

Everything works now... Thanks for the help...

Comment: Great, would you mind marking one answer correct? (whichever one feels closest to what you needed). Upvoting others is a great way to give back too.